# Сортировка в DataGridView при использовании ADO.NET Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Подскажите почему при указании DataSource сортировка по столбцам уже не работает? Делаю что-то на подобии:

```
using (var context = new TestEntity)
{
    dataGridView.DataSource = context.Where(x => x.ID == _ID);
}
```

При использовании в качестве источника DataTable сортировка работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.90).aspx) при программном (не декларативном) указании datasource не предоставляются встроенные возможности сортировки.

Цитата

> Для привязки источника данных, реализующего интерфейс System.Collections.IEnumerable, следует программно задать свойству DataSource элемента управления GridView значение источника данных и вызвать метод DataBind. При использовании этого метода, элемент управления GridView не предоставляет встроенные возможности сортировки, обновления, удаления и разбиения по страницам. Данные возможности следует реализовать при помощи соответствующих событий.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию:)